# Import ICD-10 codes xml file to database

Tags: xml, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, icd

I have a xml file with ICD-10 codes, downloaded from http://www.who.int/classifications/icd/en/
How can i import it to sql database?

Comment: can you give me the link to the download fine

Comment: Hi. Here is the link to download the file. http://apps.who.int/classifications/apps/icd/ClassificationDownload/DLArea/Download.aspx
You will have to login to access this page.
I followed this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860153/icd10-mysql-tables
But i need 2016 version instead of 2010 version. Plain text tabular file format is not available for it.

Comment: I think that your question is how to get the file in the proper format.

Comment: @MZaragoza I am trying to find a way to import the contents given in the xml file to sql database.

Comment: can you post a sample of the XML

Answer (score 1):

I like to convert my xml to json. I just think that its easier to work with

A simple trick:

First you need to `gem install json`, then when using Rails you can do:

```
require 'json'
Hash.from_xml('<variable type="product_code">5</variable>').to_json #=> "{\"variable\":\"5\"}"
```

**Example:**

```
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
xml = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/ruby-on-rails-4')).body
new_json = Hash.from_xml(xml).to_json
new_json.each do |data|
  Model.create(name: data.name)
end
```

now you can loop from the hash and do what you have to do.

I hope that this helps